# Отображение текста при наведении на ссылку

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть секция "Отзывы". В секции, наполнение снизу вверх:
1. сам отзыв в h5
2. параграф  с именем и должностью оставившего отзыв.
3. footer: 3 div (нужен для оформления) внутри каждого ссылка c фото, оставившего отзыв.

Что нужно: при наведении на фото-ссылку, появлялся текст отзыва в h5 (см. п.1) и имя должность в параграфе  (см. п.2). Виден всегда один из отзывов, например при первой загрузке страницы, пустого места в заголовке h5 или параграфе быть не должно. Доп (моя хотелка): Желательно подгружать текст из внешнего текстового файла, если такое возможно.

Я: начинающий, пытаюсь пока освоить верстку на скачаных из интернета psd шаблонах. В этом случае, мне кажется, что реализовать на css такое нельзя, т.к. ссылка идет в самом низу, отображаемый текст вверху.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это домашнее задание !

Comment: http://bootstrap-ru.com/204/javascript.php#tooltips

Comment: Согласен с Geyan, довольно странный вопрос, учитывая что есть bootstrap и тому подобные вещи. Насчет реализации на css - тут вы тоже не совсем правы. С современным css3 и не такое можно вытворить (подсказка - :hover для обработки наведения, а элементы в :before и :after, которые будут иметь position absolute)

Comment: 1.что за домашнее задание?

Comment: на этом сайте уже есть примеры, но они работают только если за ссылкой идет div а не наоборот